# How to choose which pictures are available to pin when adding a pin it button to a page?

Tags: javascript, html, pinterest, pin-it-sdk

I am developing a webpage that has a pin-it button on it. The problem is that when I click on it, the popup window that appears shows images that I don't know where are retrieved from because they are not present in the current page.

Is there a way to specify which images to be available to pin?

I have added this code just before the end of body tag:

```
<script  src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js" async defer></script>
```

And this is how I am placing the button:

```
<a data-pin-do="buttonBookmark" href="https://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/">
<img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pinit_fg_en_rect_gray_20.png" />
</a>
```

is it possible to do what I need? if it is, how?

Jaime

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the right Pinterest `Button Type` for your needs. It looks like you're using the `Any Image` button. Perhaps try using the `Image Hover` button or even the `One Image` button which would need `data-pin-do="buttonPin"` added to the images you want to show the `Pin It` button.

Regardless which one you use, I tend to also place `data-pin-no-hover="true"` on specific images that I don't ever want to be pinned (like a header graphic). If a user has the Pinterest extension installed on their browser, that automatically scrapes an entire page and adds a Pin It button to all of the images. The `data-pin-no-hover="true"` overrides that.

[Example of the hover button.](http://www.maurices.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=80997076)

[Example of the static button.](http://m.maurices.com/category/index.jsp?categoryId=80997076)